# Issue with file upload in codeigniter with CSRF enabled on server

Tags: php, codeigniter, csrf

I am working on file upload with CSRF enabled in my project in codeigniter framwork. The code is working fine in localhost but it is not working on server.

Whenever I am trying to select the image/file to upload and submit the form, it shows CSRF "request is not allowed error" and when submit the form without select the image/file, it works fine.

I have already set `$config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE;` in config file

Comment: I had this and ended up going into the CI system file and disabling the CSRF check if a certain query string was passed. This is obviously not super secure and there's almost certainly a better way, but I didn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `application/config/config.php` file and check for `$config['csrf_protection']` is `true` or `false`.

if its `$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;` make it `$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;`.

Hope that will solve your problem.

Comment: I want to keep it enabled... and as I mentioned in my question, it works fine in local

Answer (score 0):

You need to crosscheck these points to use CSRF in CodeIgniter

1. Enable `$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;`
2. Load the form helper liberary `$this->load->helper('form');`
3. User form_open() tag to open the form and this will auto include the CSRF token in your form Or you have to add the csrf token in your form.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this same problem and if you have not found a solution or anyone else looking for a solution. I found this worked for me.

You will want to add the route to the config file in your application/config folder

$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = 'your_controller/function'];

I found that when I kept the CSRF enabled but the upload continued fail even when I was using the form_open_multipart from the form helper library.

Once I added the above snippet the problem ceased to exist.

You want to be very specific when you are handling the upload because this is the biggest known attack method. But this is also another subject.